# How to globally turn off shadowing messages (symbol::shdw)? Or any other 'good practice' suggestions?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following situation:

```
On[t::shdw]

Message[t::shdw,"t","Foobar","Dork"]
-> t::shdw: Symbol t appears in multiple contexts Foobar; definitions in context Dork may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>

Off[t::shdw]
Message[t::shdw,"t","Foobar","Dork"]
-> **No Warning**

<<MASStoolbox`
-> t::shdw: Symbol t appears in multiple contexts {MASStoolbox`MASS`,Global`}; definitions in context MASStoolbox`MASS` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>
```

How can that be? Does `On` and `Off` only affect the current Notebook and have no effect when loading packages? If so, how can one get rid of messages like these? How should shadowing errors be treated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for what you observed is that the statement `Off[t::shdw]` disables a shadowing message for the symbol `t` that is currently on the `$ContextPath`, but not for another `t`, created during the loading of another package. You should disable shadowing message for that second `t`, if you don't want to see it. Here is an example:

```
In[1]:= Off[Test1`a::shdw]
In[2]:= 
BeginPackage["Test`"]
a
EndPackage[]

Out[2]= Test`
Out[3]= a

In[5]:= BeginPackage["Test1`"]
a
EndPackage[]

Out[5]= Test1`
Out[6]= a
```

Here, no message was generated.

Generally, however, I would not want to disable shadowing messages, since shadowing is a serious problem. Shadowing simply means that there is more than one context currently on the symbol search path (`$ContextPath`), containing symbol(s) with the same (short) name. Basically, if  symbol is shadowed, *and* you refer to it by its short name (that is, symbol without its containing package), you have no guarantee which of the several symbols with the same short name will actually be used. So, the correct way to deal with this is to avoid shadowing altogether, which is always possible, if not always convenient.

The simplest way to avoid shadowing is to load the package you need into the private section of your package, which starts after the line `` Begin["`Private`"] ``. You do that by calling `Needs[your-package]`, as always. In this way, the context of the loaded package does not stay on the `$ContextPath` together with your package's context. The worst case is when you need to load two packages with conflicting symbols. One way out is to construct a wrapper package for one of them, which would load that one privately and rename the conflicting symbols. This may be inconvenient though, since you'd have to rename all functions in a package, even those that don't conflict. Here is an example of a  more flexible variant:

First package:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
g[x_?NumericQ] := x^2;
EndPackage[];
```

Second package:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
g[x_?NumericQ] := x^3;
EndPackage[]
```

Main package:

```
BeginPackage["Main`"];
f::usage = "A test function of a single  argument";
Begin["`Private`"];

Block[{$ContextPath = $ContextPath},
  Needs["Test`"];
  (* Define first delegate private function *)
  g1 = Symbol["g"]];


Block[{$ContextPath = $ContextPath},
  Needs["Test1`"];
  (* Define second delegate private function *)
  g2 = Symbol["g"];
];

f[x_] := g1[x]*g2[x]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Now, provided that the system knows where to find your packages:

```
In[2]:= Needs["Main`"]

In[3]:= f[x]
Out[3]= Test`g[x] Test1`g[x]

In[4]:= f[2]
Out[4]= 32
```

And we used two conflicting symbols for the same public function. Using `Block` above served to localize the code where the first or second definition of `g` is used. Note that there is some inconvenience with this method in that we need to use `Symbol["your-symbol-name"]`, to delay the parsing until run-time.

A much simple method is to just refer to symbols by their long names. In the above, we could just use `` Test`g `` and `` Test1`g `` and then there is no need for the heavy machinery. This is somewhat less flexible however, since you have to "hard-code" the symbol's context into the code.

Comment: +1 I was just typing (almost) exactly the same answer... One comment: if phantomas really wants to turn off all shadowing messages, he should use `Off[General::shdw]`

Comment: @Simon  Indeed, I missed that one.

Comment: @Leonid, look at the changes I made to see how to do it.

Comment: @Leonid, 'The simplest way to avoid shadowing is to load the package you need into the private section ...' didn't know that. It does the trick for me, thanks. Before, I was reading another package inside of my package (before the Private section) and removing it manually from the $ContextPath :-) Much better now.

Comment: @rcollyer  Thanks, I did and I got it.

Comment: " you have no guarantee which of the several symbols with the same short name will actually be used" I'm sure there's a definite order.

Comment: @masterxilo Yes, but it has changed from version to version, is not documented, and can't be relied upon. In general, the fact of shadowing in most cases means suboptimal code design. The only case where it isn't so that comes to mind is when you need to load two packages exporting symbols with same short name. I view this as a shortcoming of the current import system, where we can't say something like "from package1 import a" or "from package1 import a as b", as we can e.g. in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `Message` to turn it off:

```
Unprotect@Message;
Message[MessageName[s_, "shdw"],___] := Null;
Protect@Message;
```

This code also emits a more helpful and correct message, and it verifies its assertions with Assert:

`````
Unprotect@Message;
Message[MessageName[s_, "shdw"], 
   rest : PatternSequence[snHeld_, pathsHeld_, newpath_]] := 
  With[{paths = ReleaseHold@pathsHeld},
   {memberpaths = Select[$ContextPath, MemberQ[paths, #] &], 
    sn = ReleaseHold@snHeld},
   Print@StringTemplate[
      "Note: Symbol `` added in context ``, so that it now appears in \
multiple contexts: ``. On the context path, it is currently found in: \
``. Definitions in the first context of the context path, ``, will \
shadow any other definitions."][sn, newpath, paths, memberpaths, 
     First@memberpaths];
   (*symbol name*)
   Assert[SymbolName@s === sn];

   (*demonstrate that First@
   memberpaths is the context used for short names*)
   Assert[ToExpression@StringTemplate[
       "Unevaluated@`` === Unevaluated@````"
       ][sn, First@memberpaths, sn
      ]
    ];

   (*and not any other context*)
   Assert@AllTrue[TrueQ][ToExpression@StringTemplate[
          "Unevaluated@`` =!= Unevaluated@````"
          ][sn, #, sn
         ] & /@ DeleteCases[paths, First@memberpaths]
     ];
   ];
Protect@Message;
`````

Try:

```
Global`Image
```

> `` Note: Symbol Image added in context Global`, so that it now appears in multiple contexts: {Global`, System`}. On the context path, it is currently found in: {System`, Global`}. Definitions in the first context of the context path, System`, will shadow any other definitions. ``

c.f. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43381/result-about-context-is-inconsistent-with-the-description-of-power-programming/119887#119887